# .NET Core Keyword not supported: 'server'

Tags: azure, sqlite, asp.net-core

The sample application on the following page does not start.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-dotnetcore-sqldb-app?pivots=platform-linux
https://github.com/azure-samples/dotnetcore-sqldb-tutorial

As stated in the documentation
After downloading the sample application and creating the DataBase to connect to, an error will occur when the database migration is executed.

```
$ export ConnectionStrings__MyDbConnection="Server=tcp:db-host.database.windows.net,1433;Database=coreDB;User ID=<username>;Password=<password>;Encrypt=true;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

```
$ dotnet ef database update
Build started...
Build succeeded.
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 3.1.3 initialized 'MyDatabaseContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite' with options: None
System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'server'.
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionStringBuilder.GetIndex(String keyword)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item(String keyword, Object value)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Storage.Internal.SqliteDatabaseCreator.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Keyword not supported: 'server'.
```

Do you know the cause?
I'm using .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: Are you really using a SQLite driver? This pattern of connection string is not supported.

Comment: The EF Core driver you're using is for **SQLite**, while the format of the connection string is for **SQL Server** ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is really use SQLite then you should check this patterns of connections string:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/connection-strings

If not, your code is accidentally calling the SQLite extension to configure your DbContext... Do a full search (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) in the entire solution for `UseSqlite` method and replace it for the desired database provider extension (probably will require a new package reference to your project)

Answer (score 0):

The cause was that SQlite was specified where SQL server should be specified.

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDatabaseContext>(options =>
        options. UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbConnection")));
```

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDatabaseContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbConnection")));
```

Thank you for your cooperation.